# Status 404 when i set an AngularJS route

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in the programmation whit angularJS
So i want to program in MVC application whit `Angular`, `Spring boot` and `thymeleaf` as themplate.

The logic with which I work is as follows:
All incoming requests first must pass through `Spring security`, this last sends the request to a login page that uses `thymeleaf`.
If the connection was done correctly then Spring security returns the request to `index.html` , at this level I want that just angular that will make the routing of the requests.

When I use only ui-router everything works fine but my url is like this `http://localhost: 8090/#!/home` it got me wrong so I used html5Mode to fix this problem
Unfortunately, the requests are sent back to Spring like this: http://localhost.com/8090/home that does not find them and displays an error of type 404

My Configuration SpringSecurity :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, true from users where username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_username as principal, roles_role as role from users_roles where user_username = ?")
                .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Pattern builder

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/dist/**","/js/**","/assets/**","/css/**","/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

My /templates/login.html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www/thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Connexion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{dist/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/login.css}"/>

</head>

<body>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
  <div class="login-form">
     <h1>Guichet unique</h1>
      <div th:if="${param.error}" class="text-warning">Login ou mot de passe incorrect</div>
      <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="text-primary">Vous avez déconnecté</div>
     <div class="form-group ">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="username" id="UserName"/>
       <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group log-status">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="Passwod"/>
       <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
     </div>
      <span class="alert">Invalid Credentials</span>
      <a class="link" href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a>
     <button type="submit" class="log-btn" >Se connecter</button>
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

/static/js/modules/routes/routes.js :

```
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('accueil', {
            url: '/acceuil',
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/Accueil/partials/accueil.html',
            controller: 'AccueilCtrl'
        })
        .state('hello', {
            url: '/hello',
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/Accueil/partials/hello.html',
            controller: 'AccueilCtrl'
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/acceuil');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to serve your index file statically to avoid this. You don't want to go through the spring request matching code, you want to let angular do the routing and make requests to the server when resources for populating the view is needed. Maybe give [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) a try?

I think [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919578/angularjs-web-application-with-spring-security#answer-23920229) answers a related issue.

Comment: The same problem, when I send a request of type http://localhost:8090/home i had There was an unexpected error (type = Not Found, status = 404).

Comment: I think [this tutorial repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular) in spring guides can help you get on the right track.